# NSPopover in Interfacebuilder with swift

Tags: swift, interface-builder, nspopover

I try to add a `NSPopover` to my swift-project with `Interface Builder`, but I cannot find the `popover` and `viewContoller` entry in the object-library of `Interface Builder` (they still appear in an obj-c project)

Is there a way to add a `NSPopover` to my swift-project with `Interface Builder` ?

Comment: You need to add popovers programmatically as popovers are dynamic natured. However you can create viewcontroller & view in the interface builder and then programmatically set the popover's viewcontroller to the one created in interface builder.

Comment: thanks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRMOwLbHUns shows it very nice